# MS Graph getting users' OnPremisesSamAccountName is always null

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MS graph in my app to perform a users search based as following
[image]

however the response is always only displayname and the onpremisessamaccountname is always null except for the signed in user it is showing

I'm not sure if this is a scope issue but here are my scopes
[image]

is there any possible way to get the onpremisessamaccountname attribute without requesting application scope. for security reasons?

So, calling MS graph API searching users with a prefix. the response should be list of users with their displayname and onpremisessamaccountname. however only the displayname is available for the list and the onpremisessamaccountname is always null except for the user himself who is searching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that, only users **synced** from on-prem AD to Azure Active
> Directory via **Azure AD Connect** have `On-premises SAM account name` value.

If users are getting **null** value for `On-premises SAM account name` attribute, it means they are created in **Azure AD** locally without any on-prem sync.

I have couple of users in my on-prem AD where I used **Azure AD Connect** to sync them like below:

[image]

From Portal, you can check those users by including **On-premises SAM account name** column with search **filter** like below:

[image]

I ran below query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) that uses **Delegated** permissions and got the response successfully like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesSamAccountName,displayName&$search="displayName:testuser"&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: Eventual
```

**Response:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The property `onPremisesSamAccountName` is only populated for customers who are synchronizing their on-premises directory to Azure Active Directory via Azure AD Connect and I would try to add `Directory.Read.All` delegated permission.

Some subset of properties on the user resource requires `Directory.Read.All` permission.